# Ломается верстка шаблона из-за PHP

Tags: php, вёрстка, html5

Делаю что-то типа блога. Но у меня проблема в том, что мой код для выведения сообщений ломает мне всю верстку. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, код и скажите, где я не прав?

```
<?php

for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
{ 
?>
<div id="contentwrap">
<section class="postinfo">
<p class="postdata postdate">
<?php
echo "<tr> 
         <td>".$postrow[$i]['date']."</td></tr>";
?></p>
<P class="postdata">By SKYnetRTX</P>
</section>
<article class="postpre">
<header>
<h3>
<?php
echo "<tr> 
         <td>".$postrow[$i]['name']."</td></tr>";
?>
</h3>

</header>

<?php
 echo "<tr> 
         <td>".$postrow[$i]['text']."</td></tr>"; 
?>

</article>
<?php
         }
?>
```

[Рисунок](http://celldweller.org/data/hash%20code.jpg).

Comment: А зачем вы ячейки (td) выводите вне таблицы? о_О Может, поэтому все ломается?)

Comment: Я пытался выводить и в рамках таблицы. Не помогает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все блин! Сам решил! Так не хватало:

```
</div>  после
<div id="contentwrap">
```

В общем должно было быть следующим образом:

```
<div id="contentwrap"></div>
```